# Apache: Failed to configure CA certificate chain

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate

Pre-note: The certificates was purchased from a vendor and are valid till 2018

Our Apache for one of our servers (Ubuntu 12.04) crashed this morning. Trying to restart Apache kept giving us the following error message

> [Wed Jun 03 12:21:51.875811 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 30534] AH01903: Failed to configure CA certificate chain!
>
> [Wed Jun 03 12:21:51.875846 2015] [ssl:emerg] [pid 30534] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information

After removing the following line from apache config

```
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/wck.bundle
```

Apache reloaded.
The server did not restart so I am sure no updates where done by accident.

I then proceeded to try and get it up and running on one of the 14.04 Ubuntu servers we own. The same problem occurred with the same certificates. I asked the guy who setup the 14.04 apache and he claims the problem we suddenly experienced today with the 12.04 server has always happened on the 14.04 server.

I tried reproducing the error on my local 14.04 by installing a new Apache and copying the certificates and one of the config files for one of the sites to my local machine. On my local machine after the setup everything worked perfectly.

I have tried comparing openssl versions, lib version between the two 14.04, but everything looks the same. I even upgraded both my local machine and the 14.04 server to ensure the libs and Apache version are identical, but the one works and the other one doesn't and I recon If I can solve this problem for the 14.04 Ubuntu server it will provide me with the information to get the ssl certificate chain up and running on the 12.04 Machine.

Does anyone have an idea why suddenly the 12.04 Ubuntu's Apache would stop working with the ssl certaficate chain and the 14.04 server also produces the same error, but my local 14.04 does not?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.